# Customize SampleIconsDefault in viewpagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am implementing SampleIconsDefault in viewpagerIndicator.
I need 2 things.

1. Customize `com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator` - Put some space etc.
2. Get `onclick` functionality of every icon in `com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator` - Currently only swipe is available. If I click on the icon, nothing happens.`

Here is the code:
SampleIconsDefault.java

```
package com.viewpagerindicator.sample;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator;

public class SampleIconsDefault extends BaseSampleActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_icons);

        mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (IconPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }
}
```

sample_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">


    <com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="#464646"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"

        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I see no way of customizing `com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator`. 
I am on a bloody deadline. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### See this code you have to do exactly as it is done here.

```
public class SampleTitlesCenterClickListener extends BaseSampleActivity implements OnCenterItemClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_titles);

    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Underline);
    indicator.setOnCenterItemClickListener(this);
    mIndicator = indicator;
}

@Override
public void onCenterItemClick(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked the center title!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: with R.layout.simple_titles.simple_titles, I am getting text instead of icons. I want icons but they need to be clickable.